# Pass variables to s3 web app through lambda invoked by API gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, serverless, lti

Basically, I have an app that needs to authenticate some Post variables (LTI consumer variables). So my thinking is that I use lambda to authenticate and serve the app in s3 with some variables. e.g. -

LTI Consumer uses POST to invoke -> https://mycoolapp.com -> API Gateway -> Lambda (to authenticate post variables) -> invokes s3 app (on success along with some variables such as userID etc..)

Is this a correct approach, if so how do I set this up?

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken, your approach certainly feasible, but technically it will not be an S3 web app anymore.

Amazon S3 have certain feature called [static webhost](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteHosting.html) that on enabling it, AWS automatically create a web server serving the files in your s3. If you have static files in them that can be an application (such as html as a web-page) then it is an S3 web app

With your approach, you are creating an API gateway which integrates with Lambda, then you can do anything on Lambda, including doing authentication, getting the app you store on s3 via s3 api and serve it back to the client. Note that now the one serving the web will be lambda not s3, so technically it's lambda based web server with files stored on S3 :)

More on Authentication, API gateway have it's [own custom authorizer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-use-lambda-authorizer.html) if you want to leverage this for Authentication. With custom authorizer, you can reuse your authorization and authentication logic for other endpoints

Comment: True, but i guess i could just have lambda return a 301 redirect to the s3 url but with a querystring attached for the app to use, and I could pass a JWT token for example rather than the full JSON etc.